# How to make my java program run faster?

Tags: java, optimization, file-io

This program runs in 0.099s on my device. I want to run it in less than 0.01s. How to make this happen. Its probably related to the reading and writing stream. This progam basically takes in a string and performs some operations on the characters of the string one by one in the method calc and returns some int value. You don't really need to understand the code. The optimizations if any has to take happen with the i/o stream or inside the method. I can't think of any other place where this optimization needs to happen.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class ride{
static int calc(String s){
char[] d=new char[s.length()];
s.getChars(0,s.length(),d,0);
int sum=1;
for(char c:d){
sum*=(c-'A'+1);
}
return sum%47;
}



public static void main(String args[]){
try{
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ride.in"));
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("ride.out");
String s;
while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
if(calc(s)==calc(br.readLine())){
fw.write("GO\n");
}
else
fw.write("STAY\n");
}
fw.close();
}
catch(IOException e){
System.out.println(e);
}
}
}
```

Comment: sum or product? sum*=   or sum+=  Also please fix your formatting

Comment: Clearly, your focus should be on readability, maintainability and robustness. Not on performance. Your code is not indented, doesn't respect the Java naming conventions, uses obscure one-letter variable names, and doesn't close its file streams. A fast, but unmaintainable incorrect program is useless. It's also unclear how you measure the time taken to run this. My guess is most of the time is taken starting the JVM.

Comment: Programs run faster if you indent them properly.  (OK ... that's a lie ... but indent your code properly anyway **before** you ask someone else to read it.)

Comment: My gut feeling is JB Nizet is right.  Moreover, my gut feeling is that if you want a program to start / run / complete in under 0.01 seconds, you need to write it in a language that compiles to a native binary.  That precludes Java.

Comment: @StephenC ... unless you compile Java to a native binary (https://www.excelsiorjet.com; codenameone on iOS). But it still may be slower than required.

Comment: Yes ... well ... Java -> native compilers are not "real Java" (IMO).  And I doubt that tools like excelsior produce code that is competitive with (say) native compiler C or C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

give bufferReader a bigger buffer size, maybe 80k or more, depend on your available ram:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ride.in"), 81920);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a BufferedReader instance, your lack of performances may not be due to I/O (even while reading multiple char, there will be only a few system calls to the underlying operating system). Of course, this depends on the file length.

So to get better performances, try starting working on the calc function. For instance, you can avoid computing the length twice.